# Не работает  для скрипта

Tags: html, internet-explorer, комментарии

Не работает <!--[if !IE]> для скрипта. Пишу

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="parallax.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Чтобы выполнялся в других браузерах, но он вообще не выполняется. Как исправить? В интернете везде так написано, но почему то не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере напутано с комментариями.
Вот рабочий пример:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--[if !IE]><!--><script>alert('test non IE')</script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><script>alert('test IE')</script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```